# Implement Jquery Datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement JQuery Datetimepicker into my MVC application. I have added all the reference into this but still throwing error

GET `http://localhost:53987/Home/assets/img/demo/m2.jpg 404` (Not Found)

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

`_Layout.cshtml` code

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Arion Pedigrees</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>

<body> 

                    <div class="navbar-header">

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                            <li class="dropdown"> 
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Reports</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left animated-2x animated fadeIn">
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("AA", "Index", "Home")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("BB", "Index", "Home")</li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>


            </nav> 
    <div class=" ">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>



        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This the code:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @class = "form-control"})
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FinishDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And then JavaScript code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#StartDate").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                $("#FinishDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
            }
        });
        $("#FinishDate").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                $("#StartDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
            }

        });


    });

</script>
```

Anyone please guide me. I do not understand where i am going wrong. The same code works for my another application. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `$` after jQuery is included in the page ? Check your view source of the page to confirm that.

Comment: @Shyju, I did not get you. If I remove $.noConflict() code then getting another error:  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function. Please help me.

Comment: Remove the `$.noConflict();` - If your then getting a _$(...).datepicker is not a function_ is because your loading another copy of `jQuery.js` after the one in your view (probably in your Layout)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Can you please guide me. Where am I am getting wrong. The same code works in another application but not in this.

Comment: Do you have a copy of jQuery.js` in your layout? (perhaps in a bundle?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Yes, it is there. I will paste it. @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, and on the top,    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

Comment: Then that is the almost certainly the reason  (you need to include the Layout code in your question)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I will edit the question now. Please have a look.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Please have a look. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` in your `Layout.cshtml` file after the `@RenderBody()`, your including a copy of `jQuery-{version}.js` (the one in your bundle) after the `jquery-ui.js` script in your view, which wipes out `jquery-ui`.

Remove the `jquery-1.12.4.js` script and the `$.noConflict();` line of code in your view, and wrap all your scripts in the view inside `@section scripts` so that the scripts are loaded in the correct order.

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#StartDate").datepicker({
            ....
        });
        $("#FinishDate").datepicker({
            ....
        });
    </script>
}
```

Note that because your bundles and the `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` in your layout are immediately before the closing `</body>` tag, it is not necessary to wrap your scripts in `$(document).ready(function () {`.

In addition, you should move your `jquery-ui.css` file into a section for styles.

In the Layout, add `@RenderSection("styles", false)` after `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` and in the view

```
@section styles {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
}
```

Comment: I am able to get the date now but getting error as well.            
   vendors.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
    at Function.ga.error (vendors.js:2)
    at ga.tokenize (vendors.js:2)
    at ga.select (vendors.js:2)
    at Function.ga [as find] (vendors.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.find (vendors.js:2)
    at new r.fn.init (vendors.js:2)
    at r (vendors.js:2)
    at getParent (bootstrap.js:798)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.js:782)
    at Function.each (vendors.js:2)

Comment: That is not related to your question (I do not even know what `vendor.js` is

Comment: Actually I have added a new layout and this vendor.js comes under assets folder. If I click on any textbox, the same error is throwing.

Comment: Again, That is not related to this question. You need to ask a new question with the relevant details and code.

Comment: Sure, Stephen.  will do that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `$.noConflict()` which disassociate jQuery from $ var, that's why, just delete that

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: If i remove $.noConflict() then I am getting this error. Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: I don't see the `<script>` tag importing that library after jquery. Could be that?

Comment: I did not get you @fejanton. Please guide me how to do this. I got stuck here. The same code works in my another application.

Comment: When you're going to use a js library, you need to import it on the html file, same way as you did on the first 2 lines of code you posted.
You should include the JQuery Datetimepicker import on line 3 like this

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.14/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>`

Comment: still not working. I have added <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimep‌​icker/2.5.14/jquery.‌​datetimepicker.js"></script>

Comment: paste me the code as it is now. Maybe a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) would be better to work on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160890/discussion-between-raj-and-fejanton).