# JQuery autocomplete function not loading

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm working on autocomplete JQuery function to populate student names in the text box. I've utilized every related JQuery library to make the autocomplete function work. When i press F12, it always throws an error which is "autocomplete is not a function". Below is my code that I'm running.

**StudentBatch.cshtml**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentName, new { id = "StudentName" })

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("This is autocomplete function");
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#StudentName").autocomplete({
            //autocomplete: {
            //    delay: 0,
            //    minLength: 1,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Student/Create",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        try {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.StudentName, value: item.StudentName };
                            }))
                        } catch (err) { }
                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "jhh", results: "jhjh"
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

**StudentController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(string Prefix)
{
    CreateUser user = new CreateUser();
    string stdid = "fae30ef0-08b2-4490-a389-3c8eb0a7cc53";
    var StudentList = user.GetAllUsers().ToList().Where(u => u.FirstName == Prefix && u.usertypeid == stdid).ToString();
    return Json(StudentList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Remove the `ToString()` from your query. (an as a side note, remove `new { id = "StudentName" }` in your `EditorFor()` - that does not add an `id` attribute, and the method already adds `id="StudentName"` anyway)

Comment: And there is no point returning all the properties of `Student` when you never use them - just use a `.Select(x => x.StudentName)` and use `return { label: item, value: item };`

Comment: Point noted. The actual issue still occurring which is on autocomplete method.

Comment: That is because your scripts are not loaded correctly. Possibly due to the issue in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745087/implement-jquery-datetimepicker/47745609#47745609)

Comment: Well I've checked that link and tried something, yet nothing happened. To be noticed when i get into the console in IE, i get to see two similar files of jquery. I don't know why it is loading two similar files.

Comment: Neither do I - I cannot see your code! But the error means that your loading a copy of `jquery.js` after `jquery-ui.js` (just as per the answer I linked to)

Comment: Now as i have followed the answer given in the link, I dont get the error of autocomplete function, but as soon as i type something in the textbox, i get the error of "POST http://localhost:2281/Student/Create 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: That means your controller method is throwing an exception

Comment: Ive added a breakpoint before the controller method, atleast it should stop at the breakpoint

Comment: @user100020 i have created similar demo which you are creating check below answer once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created similar demo which you are creating.

**Model**

```
public class CreateUser
 {
     public string StudentName { get; set; }
     public string StudentId { get; set; }
 }
```

Controller

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    // GET: Student
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create(string prefix)
    {
        List<CreateUser> studentList = new List<Models.CreateUser>()
        {
            new CreateUser { StudentId = "1" , StudentName = "Student1"},
            new CreateUser { StudentId = "2" , StudentName = "Student2"},
            new CreateUser { StudentId = "3" , StudentName = "Student3"},
            new CreateUser { StudentId = "4" , StudentName = "Student4"},
            new CreateUser { StudentId = "5" , StudentName = "Student5"},
            new CreateUser { StudentId = "6" , StudentName = "Student6"},
            new CreateUser { StudentId = "7" , StudentName = "Student7"},
        };

        var searchlist = (from student in studentList
            where student.StudentName.Contains(prefix)
            select student).ToList();

        return Json(searchlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

View

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.CreateUser
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
    .ui-autocomplete {
        max-height: 100px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    /* IE 6 doesn't support max-height
     * we use height instead, but this forces the menu to always be this tall
     */
    * html .ui-autocomplete {
        height: 100px;
    }

    .ui-autocomplete-input {
        width: 300px;
    }
</style>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentName, new { id = "StudentName" })
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#StudentName").autocomplete({
            //autocomplete: {
            //    delay: 0,
            //    minLength: 1,
            source: function (request, response)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Student/Create",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { prefix: request.term },
                    success: function(data) {
                        try {
                            response($.map(data,
                                function (item)
                                {
                                    return { label: item.StudentName, value: item.StudentName };
                                }));
                        } catch (err) {
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            messages:
                {
                noResults: "jhh", results: "jhjh"
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Same error occurring at my side "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Alright now, the problem was with the name of the Controller action. As i changed the name the code started working and displayed the desired result.

Comment: Just a quick question before marking it an answer, I previously added a linq query to display the name from the database. Please suggest if the particular linq statement is right or not.

Comment: it is correct but you can also try Contains in where clause.

Comment: @user100020 is there anything else

Comment: Right now im using these lines to fetch student names

var StudentList = user.GetAllUsers().ToList();
var searchlist = (from student in StudentList
                              where student.FirstName.Contains(Prefix)
                              select student).ToList().Select(x=>x.FirstName);

the data appears in the searchlist but doesn't appear in textbox suggestion

Comment: you are selecting FirstName from collection then you need to change value of autocomplete . return { label: item.StudentName, value: item.StudentName };

Comment: You mean i have to write FirstName in place of StudentName in Label?